# What's the name of the "drawer" used at banks/forex counters?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

I couldn't find any Google images, but you've probably encountered them at some point. It's  a sliding "drawer" that allows you to exchange documents/money back and forth with the guy behind the glass.

Side question: What's the name of the place where the clerk sits in this configuration? Is it a booth, a counter, a cubicle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These devices are sometimes called cash **scoops** or cash **trays**.

They are well illustrated in:

> [Architectural Armour](https://www.architecturalarmour.com/security-products/cash-handling/cash-scoops-and-trays)
>
> [image: "cash and document/shallow scoops" with metal tray]

and

> [Architectural Armour](https://www.architecturalarmour.com/content/Products/Cash%20Handling/Cash%20Scoops%20and%20Trays/Combination%20%20Cash%20%26%20Document%20Tray%20Scoop.pdf)
>
> [image: "bulk cash & document transfer tray, combination tray" with bottom of window with cash in tray and diagram]

Your side question depends on the actual furniture and layout so cannot be answered uniquely.

Answer (score 1):

There is no clear dictionary entry but the name ["*transaction drawer*"](https://www.google.com/search?q=transaction%20drawer) seems to be what it's mostly sold under. There are also mentions of "*transaction window*" for the glass above the drawer.

The clerk at a bank works at the "*bank counter*" or a desk. For a ticket sales point, you would call it a "*ticket booth*" or ["*box office*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_office).